# How to know the total size of a file before downloading it in linux

Tags: linux, ftp

I have two linux machines machine1 and machine2(ftp server).

I am going to download a file from machine2 to machine1. The file is located
in **machine2/root/vdo.mp4**,

and i need the total size of this file before the download begins.

Is there any way to achive this.

**UPDATE :** 
How i got the total file size. I ran below command :

```
du -hs FILE_NAME
```

Comment: No, there's no way, with FTP it's always a guess how large the files are ... what have you tried? A simple `dir` will show the file sizes.

Answer (score 3):

FTP supports getting the total size of a file before download

```
SIZE filename
```

The SIZE command (Return the size of a file) is defined in RFC 3659.

Comment: size command returns on below format.. this command not valid when we want to get any video or .gz file
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1257    1341       3    2601     a29 a.out

I used : du -sh file_name to get the total file size.